# Equivalent of Ahead Of Time Compilation in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Like we have AOT in angular where the HTML and typescript code is converted into efficient JS code during the build phase which makes the app load faster.

Do we have something similar in React?

Comment: Isn't it Server Side Rendering you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

There's just the Typescript or Babel transpilation, which transforms JSX code into common JavaScript.

So for example the code

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

is compiled to

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var App = function () {
    return React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello World");
};
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

So basically `<h1>Hello World</h1>` into `React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello World");`. That's all.

You could add more stuff to your Babel/Typescript-Compiler (like presets and plugins, eg. babel-plugin-relay), but over all it's nothing more than a simple transpilation step.

See also:

- [JSX-Concept](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html)
- [Babel Compiler](https://babeljs.io/)

Comment: I believe it's exactly AoT. If it was JiT we would have browser transpiling JSX.

Comment: I always make a difference between transpilation and compilation, but maybe you're right. I removed the paragraph.